# For mysql server we have installed phpmyadmin tool like which tool is opt for Oracle server?

Tags: oracle

We dont have a lot experience in oracle, Previously we have used mysql by installed phpmyadmin tool. We have try open by the putty using the sqlplus command, but its not working. We hope some of the environment need to be installed for that. So we decided to install tool, it will fetch & show the result like mysql phpmyadmin.

Comment: SQLPlus should be installed if the database is, what do you mean by "not working"? Can't it find the command or can't you figure out how to use it?

Comment: Yes cant figure out, when we type the command "sqlplus" we got the error message "bash: sqlplus: command not found". Help to find easy way?

Comment: Try downloading SQL Developer: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle comes with a web-based tool called "Enterprise Manager". This is installed by default (usually accessed through: https://localhost:1158/em)

I guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, your answer is very useful to me.